# Git exclude a commit in a branch

Tags: git, commit, revert

I have a commit, I have stored in a branch, because this should go only to a specific box.

I have merged it to the branch master, but not the branch dev, that I use locally.

Now, by mistake I merged master to dev and that introduced this commit to dev.

I know can git revert sha, to branch dev; but since this is going to introduce a commit that undoes that commit (I am guessing, I haven't exactly tried this), when I merge master, will this commit be undone too?

If so, how do I undo this commit only from the branch dev.

And oh, `git reset HEAD^1` --hard is not an option because there are other commits on master, after the un-needed commit.

If reset back again and apply is the only option, then how do I only merge those extra commits from master other than the un-needed commit.

Update:

Here is the commit tree. Looks complex. I have pointed to the commit, that I don't need in the dev. (I have also removed any personally identifiable information, thanks for understanding. It is so much simpler to screenshot gitk than to ascii art.)
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible to ascii-art this as I'm not totally clear where the merge commits are in relation to the unwanted commit?

Comment: In svn you can Merge ranges of revisions, 1-19, 49, 52-90... I am sure that you can do this in git as well.

Comment: @SeanJA: I'm not sure analogy to svn is the best way to an answer. In particular, with git, if you start with `A - B - C` and remove `B` to get `A - C'`, the commit `C'` is not the same as the commit `C`, because it does not have the same parent. So sure, you can construct a second branch consisting of the original commits with the desired one missing, and then merge that, but you won't have merged the original branch.

Comment: @Jerfromi Ah, my bad... I am still learning my git-fu

Comment: OK, just to be clear is your normal workflow to merge dev into master but not the other way around?  It looks like a simple `git reset --hard HEAD^` will undo the bad merge, then it's a matter of working out how you get the changes that you do need into dev without pulling in the master only commit. As these are based on master, they may need to be cherry-picked.

Comment: Charles, Yes, you are right. Thanks. Now if you could put that in the answer, I can accept it. I am wondering, if cherry pick creates a "new commit" then will it cause any problem of double applying it, to master, next I merge dev to master?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On a scratch copy of your branch, `git rebase --interactive` and drop the unwanted commit. Alternatively, you could create a new branch upstream of the unwanted commit and `git cherry-pick` the desired commits onto it.

There are probably more ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

git reflog, then git reset --hard  are your friends to undo mistakes.

In order to avoid a single commit when merging a branch, this is what I have just used in my project:

- Assume: merge from branch B to head.
- Identify revid of commit to be avoided (R0)
- Identify revid of commit just prior to R0  (R1)

  ```
  git merge <R1>
  git merge -s ours R0
  git merge B
  ```